# Using Ionic 2 or 3, how can I check if a file exists on my server?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm making an Ionic app.  I want to display a certain image if it exists on my server, or a different one if it doesn't.  How do I test for this?

I've tried `http.head(url)`, and it fails every time, even when the url is a valid jpg.

In Chrome developer tools, I can see the request for the jpg return 200, but it still fails.  The error is something like No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  I don't think I need to set this on the server, because the image displays just fine in Ionic if I just manually tell it to display it.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: have you tried https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/

Comment: Yes, I am using ionicframework.com/docs/native/http.  That's the "http" I was referring to.  I don't think livereload is applicable in this question, since I'm trying to find out if a file exists on a remote server, not the localhost.